# How can I figure out how SSL is installed on a server using Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, cloudflare

I've acquired a Debian 11 server that is using apache to serve a site. SSL is installed on the site, working properly, and the certificate is provided by Cloudflare.

I've gone through all of the apache configuration files and can't find where the active SSL certificates are or how Apache is seeing them.

I've ran `grep -r 'SSL' /etc/httpd` and nothing comes up. I was expecting there to be something like `SSLCertificateFile`.

I can see some certificates in `/etc/letsencrypt/live` and also some certificates in `/etc/ssl`.

I need to find what certificates are being used by this server and how they're hooked up to Apache so that I can replicate it on another server.

Any tips on where I can find this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword there is probably:

> the certificate is provided by Cloudflare

That implies that  your website uses Cloudflare.

And when you can't find SSL settings for your webserver: then most likely your server is not configured to support SSL/TLS at all.

You're  are probably using what Cloudflare calls "Flexible SSL":

> **Cloudflare Flexible SSL**: secure connection between your visitor and CloudFlare, but **no secure connection between CloudFlare and your web server.
>
> You don't need to have an SSL certificate on your web server**, but
> your visitors still see the site as being HTTPS enabled.
> [Source](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416)

You can probably confirm that in your Cloudflare management console.

---

Based on your comments:

It appears that  the above is not quite the case.

Apache is indeed not configured to support HTTPS, but Cloudflare does connect over HTTPS to your server. But your server does not use Apache httpd for HTTPS, instead it uses HAProxy to serve HTTPS content.

Comment: I took a look in the Cloudflare console and it says `Your SSL/TLS encryption mode is Full`. I did also take a look though on the server with `httpd -M` and didn't see any SSL module enabled.

Comment: Can you actually connect to your server using HTTPS? Is it even listening on TCP port 443?

Comment: Then the question: is apache the web server used for https content? Check for what  is listening on the default https port 443 with for example `ss -tlpn`

Comment: The output of that command for port 443 is: `LISTEN  0 3000 *:443  *:*  `. But yes I can access the site in the browser using https.

Comment: Oh, I realize I needed to be root to see the services that were running on that port. I ran `netstat -ltnp` and it shows something called haproxy listening there. Looks like I'll read through the docs there to see what's up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: HAProxy ended up having a `Timeout Server` directive in its config that was set to 60 seconds. Increasing this fixed the issue.